# Firefox Responsive Design Mode - Touch Simulation drag not working

Tags: firefox, responsive-design, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to use Firefox Developer edition during web-app development.
When I try to Drag elements or Drag to scroll - it doesn't work. Moreover it emits the CLICK even instead.

Is there anyway to make it work?
In Chrome it works. But the response time is slower and it can't be in "mobile mode" without opening dev-tools. So I'm trying to use Firefox.

Thank you